# Object type inside array using AJV

Tags: jsonschema, ajv

I want to know the correct way to define a **schema** to validate with **AJV**.

The following schema must contain an **array of objects**.
These objects may have mandatory properties.

```
module.exports = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "oneField": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                     "oneField": { "type": "string" },
                     "twoField": { "type": "number" }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "required": ["oneField"],
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

This schema was just for illustration kkk.

I thank the help of all!

Comment: The language on stack overflow is English only. Please fix your question

Comment: required: [oneField] Is this correct syntax without quotes as array value?

Comment: I used it only for representation.  but i will put.

Comment: type: "decimal" is not defined in JSON Schema. Use "integer" or "number" instead.

Comment: Ok. I made the switch

Answer (score 0):

If you try this schema with some minor modifications at [jsonschema.dev](https://jsonschema.dev) it is working as expected:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "oneField": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                     "oneField": { "type": "string" },
                     "twoField": { "type": "integer" }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "required": ["oneField"],
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```